# Error in getting navigation property in a many to many relationship in entity framework core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, many-to-many, navigation-properties

I have two entities that are connected in a many to many relationship as follows

```
public class Fee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

   ----Ignored for brevity----

    public virtual ICollection<ClassFee> ClassFees { get; set; }

}

public class StudentClass
{

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Label { get; set; }
    ---Ignored for brevity---
    public virtual ICollection<ClassFee> ClassFees { get; set; }

}

 public class ClassFee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Display(Name ="Fee")]
    public int FeeId { get; set; }
    [Display(Name ="Class")]
    public int ClassId { get; set; }

    ---ignored for brevity---

    [ForeignKey("FeeId")]
    public Fee Fee { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ClassId")]
    public StudentClass Class { get; set; }
}
```

The following is my FeesController class where I intend to get the details of a given fee and the list of classes the fee is applied to

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var fee = await _context.Fees
            .Include(cf => cf.ClassFees)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
        if (fee == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return View(fee);
    }
```

I was expecting that with this, I should be able to have the class for the fees in the view by calling `classFeeEntityInstance.class.label` 
to get the label for the class but it returns null. Also when I put a breakpoint on the method and run the code, the classfee.class is returned as null

I have also tried to do the following to see if I could eagerly load the class in the query but it does not seen to be possible to find the class from the classfee with the ThenInclude caluse as follows

```
.Include(cf => cf.ClassFees).ThenInclude(f=>f.Class)
```

but the f.Class does not exist at that point because the intellisence in Visual Studio does not suggest it and it underlines it immediately I try to add it.

Below is how I wish to use the class under the classFees in my view

```
@foreach (ClassFee classFee in Model.ClassFees)
{
   @classFee.Class.Label
}
```

But the Class.Label throws up a null reference exception when the code is run

The application is being built on ASP.NET-Core 3.1 with Entity Framework 3.1

I will appreciate any guide to resolve this
Thank you

Comment: Have you tried to build it with the `ThenInclude`? There is a [known issue](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/8237) with Intellisense for `ThenInclude`.

Comment: @TylerHundley, It worked. Waoh! Thank you so much. Please make an answer with your comment so I can accept it.

Comment: Done. Yeah I ran into this the other day and was trying to figure out what was going on, turns out it works like you'd expect, just doesn't tell you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go ahead and try to build it using `ThenInclude`, it should work. There is a [known issue](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/8237) with Intellisense and `ThenInclude`.